# Google API inserts event with the time 1h later as given

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

I insert an event with [Google Calendar API for Python client](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_python?hl=de)  and somehow the time there is 1 hour later than intended.

Here's the snippet. 
Imports:

```
import gdata.calendar.data
import gdata.calendar.client
import gdata.acl.data
import atom.data
```

Connect to the Google Calendar:

```
calendar_client = gdata.calendar.client.CalendarClient(source='noApp')
calendar_client.ClientLogin('account@gmail.com', 'password', calendar_client.source)
```

Create event:

```
event = gdata.calendar.data.CalendarEventEntry()
date='2012-10-29T18:30:00.001Z' # This is the time of event that I want to insert
event.when.append(gdata.calendar.data.When(start=date))
```

And finally, insert the event

```
new_event = calendar_client.InsertEvent(event)
```

As a result I have in the calendar the time 19:30 on 29-th of October, and not 18:30.
I tried to change the time zone to '000Z' instead of '001Z' in the date variable, but it didn't help. 
Of course, I can subtract an hour in advance, but why does it happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`18:30:00.000Z` and `18:30:00.001Z` are given in the same timezone, namely `Z` for UTC, but separated by one millisecond -- since the `0` you changed to `1` was in the fractional seconds part of the timestamp.

If you want to give the API times in CET rather than UTC, you could try something like `2012-10-29T18:30:00+01:00` (if the API supports RFC-3339 timestamps). Or, if that doesn't work, convert your desired time to UTC first.